# font size problems

Tags: faces, fonts

I just set up a new Linux workstation, and I'm having some problems with fonts in Emacs.

Evaluating this works:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Terminus")
```

...but the size of the face is tiny.  If I try the same trick to change `:size` instead of `:family`, *the results are unpredictable*.

***Sometimes***, I can get a larger font by evaluating

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :size 197)
```

This font, when I get it, is too large.

Acording to the xfontsel, there are plenty of available sizes for this font that lie between the very tiny size I got at the beginning and the too-large size I got with `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :size 197)`, ***but I can't get Emacs to use any one of these intermediate sizes.***

FWIW, I also tried `customize-face`, and the results are basically the same.

How can I troubleshoot this problem further?

Comment: Don't know about sizes, but I strongly recommend to use `:font "Terminus-16"` instead.

Comment: @wasamasa: thanks for the suggestion, that solved the problem.  More specifically, using `:font "Terminus-xx"`, for suitable values of `xx` achieves the desired effect.